# Add to home screen menu link

Tags: javascript, button, screen

Is it possible to create a button using vanilla Javascript inside my Progressive Web App that works the same as the add to home screen button?

For example my button would say "click to add this App to your device" when clicked the pwa would be added to the home screen of the device.

Comment: Do you mean to add as a bookmark? Because otherwise you won't be able to perform such a high-permission action via JS

Comment: Would a bookmark add the icon to the homescreen? that what I want to do but like you said i don't think it is possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can listen to the `beforeinstallprompt` event and then show a button on your template as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/).

Your code might be like the following:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  // You can save the event in order to trigger the prompt later (see below)
  deferredPrompt = e;

  // Update UI notify the user they can add to home screen.
  // With this you can show the Add to home screen button.
  showInstallPromotion();
});
```

If you then want to show the A2HS (Add To Home Screen) dialog, you can invoke the `prompt()` method:

```
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
  btnAdd.style.display = 'none';

  // Show the prompt
  deferredPrompt.prompt();

  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
  deferredPrompt.userChoice
    .then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
});
```

---

[I wrote a series of articles](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da) about Progressive Web Apps, if you are interested in learning more details.